# How can I allow unsafe ports in Ionic App?

Tags: typescript, api, cordova, ionic-framework, mobile

I am trying to access an API in my Ionic App over the port 6666. Because this port is recognized as something like an unsafe port, I get this error message:
[net::ERR_UNSAFE_PORT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7N8f9.png).

In Chrome on Desktop, it´s possible to allow such ports by adding `--explicitly-allowed-ports=xxx`, but how can I fix this problem on the mobile browser with Ionic?